# CardView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, cardview

I'm looking for a way to dynamically generate card-like controls that look like these:

[image]

I have been doing some search and have found [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/introduction_to_lollipop/#settingup) that shows you how to implement CardView on a **Xamarin.Android project**. But I'm using Xamarin.Forms so I can compile for iOS as well.

I also tried to use a ListView with ViewCells and a couple StackLayout tags, but wasn't able to even get close to that, here is the code:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height="300">
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding UserAvatar}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding UserName}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Image Source="{Binding BittImage}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I'm pretty new to Xamarin, so if I'm missing something basic, please let me know guys.

Comment: only some links... https://github.com/cesartomatis/Xamarin-Forms-CardView  https://github.com/keannan5390/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/CardView  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/208640/#Comment_208640 http://danielhindrikes.se/xamarin/xamarin-forms-android-cardview/

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. Use a ListView, with a Frame as the root element and a margin, and set the background color of the ListView as appropriate. This should give you the card look. Then you fill in the card as you require.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" BackgroundColor="Gray">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height="300">
                <Frame HasShadow="true" Margin="5">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding UserAvatar}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding UserName}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Image Source="{Binding BittImage}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying different order/arrangement of controls but it is showing only blank frames (1 frame per record)